# Change drag ghost-image size

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that when I drag an image, the dragged image size changes, depending what I specify it to?  For example, when I drag the image, I want the ghost image to change to a larger size (500) in this case, but could be anything really.

Javascript:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <style>

        /* Pikachu fits in the container */
        .size {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
        }
        .size img {
            z-index:10;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="size">
        <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410195936/pokemon/images/archive/e/e1/20150101093317!025Pikachu_OS_anime_4.png" >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/89t4902d/) ?

Comment: I edited my post, realized it was confusing, jQuery has nothing to do with it, so edited it all out.  All I want is when you drag the image, I would like that dragged "ghost-image" to be a different size.

Comment: Well, there is no big difference, just select the appropriate element [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rbuergws/) .

Comment: @Snorlax do you mean when you drag an image on any webpage to the desktop, it shows a transparent "ghost-like" image? Or do you want the user to be able to drag the image around the page, as in the fiddle?

Comment: @Snorlax I think I see what you mean now, check my updated answer and let me know if it's what you wanted

Answer (score 5):

**Interpretation 1**
If you mean "ghost image" as in, the image copy that shows when you click and drag an image on any website, as you drag it to a folder (see screenshot below illustrating what I mean) then you can do that with the new [HTML5 draggable label](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/). You can see more examples [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html), and you should read up on [`setDragImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29):

```
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "URL to 500px image";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

[image: 'ghost' example]

If you don't want to have to make a 500px copy of the image, you can change the size as follows, with a [working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/51uss7sm/1/):

```
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var dragIcon = document.createElement("img");
    dragIcon.src = "http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140410195936/pokemon/images/archive/e/e1/20150101093317!025Pikachu_OS_anime_4.png";
    dragIcon.style.width = "500px";
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(dragIcon);
    div.style.position = "absolute"; div.style.top = "0px"; div.style.left= "-500px";
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(div, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

It's kind of hacky though, as we need to crate a `div` element, as `setDragImage()` will show the `img` element at full size if passed an `img`.  Then, we need add it to the page, and then move it off the page, as [it's required that the element be visible](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-setdragimage) (so `display:none` isn't allowed)

**Interpretation 2**
Now, if you mean change the size of an image as you move it around the page, then you can do that with jQueryUI's [`.draggable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/):

```
$(function() {
    $( ".size" ).draggable({
        opacity:0.6,
        drag: function(event,ui) {
            $("div.size").width(500);
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {
            $("div.size").width(200);
        }
    });

    $("div.size").width(200);

});
```

Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/9L4hxk1j/

Comment: It seems that adding an `img` element with a specific size (with a `display` other than `inline`) works on Chrome but not Firefox. On Firefox it ignores the width/height, whether it is set as attributes (`<img src="my-img.png" width="100px" height="50px" />`) or added later as the `img` element's width & height (`var img = new Image(); img.width = '100px'; img.height = '50px';`). Resizing a `div` works fine on both browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple little way using canvas that keep the image aspect ratio based on whatever width you want.

```
function onDrag(src, width, e){

  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = width;
        ctx.canvas.height = img.height * (width / img.width);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ctx.canvas, 40, 20);
  }

  img.src = src;
}
```

If you want to base the aspect ratio off a height instead just switch around the width's and heights.

Comment: This technique works with some fixes. First, you have to call setDragImage() in the primary event callback – it won't work if you try to call it later when the image loads. So, render your image before you get here. Second, the size arguments to drawImage should be ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height instead of img.width, img.height.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Can you give an example please?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess How could you render the image before you get there?